# Matlab fmincon always zero

Tags: matlab

I have a function f(x),
when I use fmincon, I received this:

```
Initial point is a local minimum that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because at the initial point, the objective function is non-decreasing 
in feasible directions to within the selected value of the optimality tolerance, and 
constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>

                                            First-order      Norm of
 Iter F-count            f(x)  Feasibility   optimality         step
    0       4    0.000000e+00    0.000e+00    0.000e+00
```

on first step. Answer is always x0, but if I find f(x0), it doesn't equal to zero! What could be the problem?

Comment: To help you it would be good to know the function you are trying and your initial guess.

Comment: yeah...you should post more details about what you´re doing. i.e: the code you have

Comment: It's complicated cause function have one more function inside... It's very big function but it  works...

Comment: and it has an Iteration cycle inside...

Comment: The first step in optimization is determination f(x0), do I understand it right? So how can it be possible that f(x0) doesn't equal to zero, but f(x) in first step is equal to zero....